# JavaScript functions browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check which functions of JavaScript the browser support which I am using? It can be any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't :)

The whole point of using a Javascript library like [jQquery](http://jquery.com/) is to avoid the necessity for doing this. They provide an abstraction layer that hides the specific implementation of Javascript across browsers, as well as providing many methods allowing you to use much less code than you would to do the same thing in standard Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

This is what [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) is for :)  [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) provides a feature list, that different browsers may or may not support, and if you're using something that is inconsistent, this will help.

`$.browser` was the old way, which tells you which browser you're on, but **don't use this** to detect features.  By using `$.browser` and saying, well this is IE8 it can't do that...that may change via an update tomorrow, that's why [feature detection](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting) is a much better way to go, which `$.support` assists with.